# Dynamic length of method arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

**Page.aspx:**

```
<a href="#" <%= ToggleUiVisibility(new List<bool>() { true, true, false }) %> >
    link
</a>
```

**C#:**

```
public string ToggleUiVisibility(List<bool> conditions)
{
    return conditions.Any(x=>!x) ? "style=\"display:none;\"" : string.Empty;
}
```

I would like to know if it's possible to do something like (psuedo code)

```
ToggleUiVisibility(true, true, argsN);

public string ToggleUiVisibility(args)
{
    // make sure each argument is a bool and trigger the same 
    // functionality as above
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [params](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) keyword:

```
public string ToggleUiVisibility(params bool[] values)
{
    // make sure each argument is a bool and trigger the same
    // functionality as above
}
```

and then you can call your method like:

```
ToggleUiVisibility(true, false, ...);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `params`:

```
public string ToggleUiVisibility(params bool[] conditions)
{
    return conditions.Any(x=>!x) ? "style=\"display:none;\"" : string.Empty;
}
```

but then your *calling* code will have to spell out each parameter individually, or wrap them in an array:

```
ToggleUiVisibility(true, true, false);  // works

ToggleUiVisibility(argsN);  // works

ToggleUiVisibility(true, true, argsN);   // does not work - you'll need to "merge" the individual values and the array

ToggleUiVisibility((new bool[] {true, false}).Concat(argsN).ToArray());  // works
```